# Is it possible to interact with components from other activities?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

Playing around with `Chrome Custom Tabs` made me realize that I cannot interact with my ``` MainActivity``ViewModel ``` when using the `Chrome Tabs`. More specifically unable to use the `ViewModel` methods in the `Chrome Tab`

This is a problem as I am running a News Application, and upon opening the `Chrome Tab` the user may choose to save this article, the problem is I have no idea how to do it with `Intents`

Here is the code to launch a custom chrome tab

```
val intent = Intent(requireContext(),MainActivity::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            requireContext(),
            100,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
        )
        
        builder.addMenuItem("test", pendingIntent);

        button.setOnClickListener {
            val url = "https://www.google.com"
            //val url = "https://www.wikipedia.org"
            val customTabsIntent: CustomTabsIntent = builder.build()
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(requireActivity(), Uri.parse(url))
        }
```

I need to implement this line of code to save the article
`article?.let { viewModel.saveArticle(it) }`

Here is how the menu looks like [Chrome tab Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbZrJ.png), I need to implement the line of code above into the `testing` list item.

I have read through the docs regarding intents, I can't seem to find anything related to this issue

Comment: What is article? is it url that you opened?

Comment: the `Article` refers to the `Article` Object, which contains the URL, title, images,etc. The Article object is essentially the `Response` I have gotten back from the API and I am storing it in my database